# Evaluating sentiment in a file with Python (basic)

Tags: python, counting

New to python here. I'd like to evaluate a file by assigning values to certain words (these are an example). A basic task but I think I'm making a relatively stupid mistake. I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

```
 import sys
    import csv
    import re
    csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
    positive = 0
    negative = 0


    for f in ['audi.csv']:
        reader = csv.reader(open(f, 'rU'), delimiter='\r', quotechar='\\')
        for w in ['love', 'great', 'happy']:
            positive += 1
        for w in ['hate', 'sad', 'sorry','test']:
            negative+= 1


    print 'positive %s sentiment. negative %s sentiment' % (positive, negative)
    print positive - negative
```

Comment: let me uderstand, you want to read file and check if words cont love,great and happy than it's positive. if word contain hat,sad,sorry,test it's negative. So if u have reader object. How are using reader object

Comment: As it's mentioned into answer you need to use reader object which is not use till now

Answer (score 1):

```
for w in ['love', 'great', 'happy']:
```

iterates over the words, so with your code `positive` would always be 3 and `negative` would always be 4. You need to iterate over each line in the reader, and over each cell in the line (perhaps, depends on your task) - and then check if that cell is `in` the positive list or `in` the negative list.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, thanks! I only need to iterate over a single list and single column.